# drawbox: error when evaluating the expression 'max'

Tags: ffmpeg

I try use the command:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -i uploads/14940964561.mp4 -vf "drawbox=x=0:y=0:w=1000:h=1000:color=white@0.2:t=max" uploads/output.mp4
```

Output error

```
ffmpeg version 2.4.3-1ubuntu1~trusty6 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on Nov 22 2014 17:07:19 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1ubuntu1~trusty6' --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --extra-cflags= --extra-cxxflags= --libdir=/usr/lib/i386-l
inux-gnu --shlibdir=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth
--enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-lib
freetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-li
brtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-li
bwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libxvid --enable-libx265 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzmq --
enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libsoxr --enable-openal --enable-libopencv
libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '14942588091.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
Duration: 00:00:08.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 350 kb/s
Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 347 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
Metadata:
  handler_name    : VideoHandler
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x856b8e0] [Eval @ 0xbf9ae638] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'max'
Last message repeated 5 times
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x856b8e0] Error when evaluating the expression 'max'
[Parsed_drawbox_0 @ 0x856b8e0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawbox_0
Error opening filters!
```

This is message the error correct.
Previously, a message and code is wrong. I'm sorry!

Message error:

I use the Ubuntu 32 bits, but the command in Windows 10 work.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard The result of the output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard now the message returned with error.
 Previously, a message and code is wrong. I'm sorry!

Comment: Again, your `ffmpeg` is probably too old. [Download a new one](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) and try again.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I use the command to upgrade of ffmpeg no Ubuntu.
Thanks very much to help.

Comment: Did the new version work?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard perfectly. It new version work.
Thanks very much to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ffmpeg` is too old.

Easiest method to upgrade is to download a recent, already compiled version. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links for Linux, macOS, and Windows.